# How to start to build OS/Kernel

Tags: c, kernel, bootloader, osdev, real-mode

I'm starting to program my first "operating system", for now I have created only the bootloader but I would like to add the kernel as well as I can. Do I need to create a linker.ld file? (I've never used a linker file)

Do I have to write the kernel in C, in assembly or do I necessarily have to use both? Please can you give me some small examples just to make me understand how to start, I'm a beginner and I don't know how to start.

In the OS directory there are only Makefile, build folder and scr folder.

This is the file **scr/boot.asm**:

```
ORG 0
BITS 16

boot:
    init:
        jmp 0x7c0:start

    start:
        cli            ; clear interrupts
        mov ax, 0x7c0
        mov ds, ax     ; data segment
        mov es, ax     ; extra segment
        mov ax, 0x00
        mov ss, ax     ; stack segment
        mov sp, 0x7c00 ; stack pointer
        sti            ; enable interrupts

        jmp $

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

**Makefile**:

```
SCR_DIR = scr
BUILD_DIR = build

main:
    nasm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/boot.bin $(SCR_DIR)/boot.asm

    qemu-system-x86_64 $(BUILD_DIR)/boot.bin
```

Comment: This is one of those questions where,  if you have to ask how to do it, you cannot do it:(  It's like 'I want to build an aircraft carrier.  I have made a rowboat, give me hints':(  I can give one hint: start by defining what services you want from your OS.

Comment: @MartinJames Obviously to start I don't want to create the new windows (God forbid ). To start I create a bootloader with a confirmation message. After the bootloader I would like to create a 'cmd' where the user can execute his commands (I would like to start from the command shutdown and rebbot as I already have the code to develop them). In the end I would like to reach an output like this:


The OS is correctly loaded to you machine.
Opening CMD...
user >>